# Attach classes before DOM is ready

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navigation element on my page that I create using the DOM API before the DOMContentLoaded. It can either be expanded or collapsed. Because I create it before the DOM is ready and attach all of the relevant classes, when I finally DO attach it to a parent node, those classes are already there.

My question is if this is possible to do with the `body` element (attach styles to it before the DOMContentLoad event).

The reason I want to do this is because there is a visual artifact from my CSS3 transitions when the class is added to the `body` element, so I'd like to have the class there beforehand, if possible.

Comment: without seeing the code we cannot help you...

Comment: it depends. code run from the <head> doesn't have a <body> to modify. if the code is run from the body, fire away at document.body.classList/className. you might also invert the CSS so that it's hidden without the class on body.

Comment: note that for CSS activation, <HTML> works as well as <body>, any document.documentElement is ALWAYS available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach classes to the `<body>` element before the `DOMContentLoaded` event if and only if your script is located after the start of the `<body>` tag.  What matters here is the position of your script.

So, this would work:

```
<body>
<script>
document.body.className += " foo";
</script>
other HTML here
</body>
```

Scripts are executed in order and elements of the DOM that are BEFORE the `<script>` tag will be in place in the DOM when the script runs.  The `DOMContentLoaded` event means that the entire DOM has finished parsing.  It doesn't mean that you can't access things that have already been parsed.

From the `<head>` section, you can also add a class to the `<html>` tag by modifying `document.documentElement` which is always available.  If it's just a parent CSS selector you're looking to trigger, this will usually work just as well as putting the class on the `<body>` tag.

---

FYI, a common work-around to avoid flicker or temporary display of unfinished objects is to have those objects specified as not visible in your CSS so as the page starts to render those objects are not yet visible.

Then, your scripts run and modify the objects, styles or classes on those objects and then the last thing your scripts do is to make the objects visible so they are only painted on the screen when they are in their final form (after your scripts have modified them).

Comment: i can use document.documentElement in this case. thanks a lot!